# How to remove background of selected image in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to get this kind of effect in React Native.
Such as removing background by touching screen, removing similar color point in one screen, and after select one point, moving finger here and there to remove the background.

Can I get this effect in react native?
If possible, which module should I use?

[image]

Comment: Yes you can, I think it is possible. You can use two view and layout absolute (Position). When you click or hold Image just remove other View

Comment: @Satelbill did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Not yet. I am still finding way.